# How to find standard Deviation using arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

> In this problem, you will write a function double stddev(double a[], int size) to compute the standard deviation of a data set.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 50;
void input(int arrays[], int &size){
    cout << "How many values do you want to enter?";
    cin >> size;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cout << "Enter a value: ";
        cin >> arrays[i];
    }
    return;
}
int mean(int a[], int size)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        sum += a[i];
    }
    double average = (double)sum /
                  (double)size;


    double sq = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    sq += (a[i] - average) * (a[i] - average);
    return sq / size;
}

double stdDev(int arr[], int size)
{
    return sqrt(mean(arr, size));
}
int main()
{
  int array[MAX];
  int size;
  input( array, size);
  mean(array,size);

  cout<<"Standerd Dev is: "<<stdDev(array,size)<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

So it allows the user to enter the values and it works when the real standard deviation is greater than 1 but if its not its prints 0. For example for `5,6,7` it prints `0` but it should be `.816...`.

I need help understanding what I'm doing wrong. Is it a mistake in my function or in my `main` function when I am calling it?

Comment: @uneven_mark it works when the standard dev is greater than 1 but if its not its prints 0 for example 5,6,7 it prints 0 but it should be .816...

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned already in the comments, you are returning the result from `mean` (which actually calculates the variance) as `int`. Therefore whatever value you are calculating in it (with `double` as type for the intermediate results) will have all its digits after the decimal point cut off.

Change your declaration to

```
double mean(int a[], int size)
```

and maybe give it a more appropriate name.

Comment: ok thanks, I will change it sorry about that honestly didn't know what standard deviation was and had to look up what it is

Comment: @user12230466 Also note that there are two formulas for the standard deviation: The population standard deviation and the empirical standard deviation. For purpose of parameter estimation from data sets the latter is used, but that formula requires the last division to be by `size-1`, not `size`.

Comment: what does the size-1 mean/do?

Comment: @user12230466 There is otherwise nothing wrong in your calculation. You just have to make sure that your functions do actually return floating point numbers whenever you want them to. The expression in the `return` statement is converted to the return type that you declared in the function signature.

Comment: @user12230466 See the following questions: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15098/sample-standard-deviation-vs-population-standard-deviation), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11421/what-is-the-difference-between-empirical-variance-and-variance), [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17890/what-is-the-difference-between-n-and-n-1-in-calculating-population-variance) (*Variance* is the same as *standard deviation*, but without the square root.)

Answer (score 0):

What is mean? It is the average of the values.

```
double mean(int a[], int size)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    if( size < 1 ) return sum;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum += a[i];
    }
    return sum / size;
}
```

What is variance? It is the difference from the mean for each value. (left as exercise for reader, how to compute mean and stddev in one pass).

```
double variance(int a[], int size)
{
    double var = 0.0;
    if( size < 1 ) return var;
    double mu = mean(a,size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        var += (a[i] - mu) * (a[i] - mu);
    }
    return var / size; //Read about Bessel correction
}
```

What is the standard deviation? It is the square root of the variance.
Oh, read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Sample_standard_deviation

```
double stdDev(int arr[], int size)
{
    return sqrt( variance(arr, size) );
}
```